# AWS lambda executes beyond timeout limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function, in python 3.6 that takes backup from RDS instance and uploads it to the S3 bucket.

I use the mysqldump binary and execute a python subprocess call to make the backup.

I can see that the backup has been made and uploaded in S3 already but the lambda function still seems to be executing and gives out an error message "Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: timeout of 0ms exceeded" after some time, but the lamda function has the timeout of 3 minutes in the first place. The error is seen when the lamda function runs for about 10 minutes.

However when i view the logs the billed duration time is about 2 minutes, which is approximately the time when the backup could be seen in S3 bucket.

Below is the lambda code i used.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    move_binary_to_temp() # moves mysqldump binary to temp folder
    command = mysql_command() # mysql command that takes backup with mysqldump
    subprocess.call(command,shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    s3.upload_file("/tmp/backup.dump","s3-bucket","tmp/backup.sql")

    return {
        'statusCode': 200

    }
```

Comment: Your lambda function is the one calling `mysqldump`? Isn't that a very long operation that will go over the Lambda timeout? Also why not just use the built-in RDS snapshot or [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html)?

Comment: So far the mysqldmup operation doesn't go over the lambda timeout, like i mentioned the whole dump is completed and can be downloaded from the S3 bucket. The execution for the function however seems to not end.

Comment: What is contained within the `mysql_command()` function? Is it defined elsewhere in this code file? Can you include it in your Question?

Comment: Maybe you have a recursion somewhere thus the function keeps executing itself?

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that you call `invoke()` for a AWS Lambda function at a certain point. That's not reflected in the code you posted. Is there some place where you do call `invoke()`? Maybe in another AWS Lambda function to trigger this one?

Comment: try adding sys.exit(0) to force exit it and see if it works

Comment: the mysql_command() provides the command string
 i.e. " mysqldump -u <user> -p <db-table>.... "
and for now, the lambda is not invoked with any triggers it's being run by aws lambda code editor as test, i haven't had the chance to setup triggers due to the error.